# Access SQL with MID don't group my rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

i'm working with VB6 and access. Then i have a table MAYOR like this:

```
Codigo     Titulo
---------  ----------------
600        Cuenta 600
60000000   Cuenta 60000000
610        Cuenta 610
6100       Cuenta 6100
6101       Cuenta 6101
61010000   Cuenta 61010000
61010001   Cuenta 61010001
61010002   Cuenta 61010002
6102       Cuenta 6102
61020000   Cuenta 61020000
61030000   Cuenta 61030000
61040000   Cuenta 61040000
```

I need select by lenght of Codigo. When i select lenght=2 then i need register
60 and 61. 
When select lenght=3 then i need 600 and 610.
When i select lenght=5 i need 60000, 61010, 61020,61030 and 61040.

i use this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW MID(CODIGO,1,4) AS CODIGOB,TITULO
FROM MAYOR
WHERE LEN(CODIGO)>=4 
ORDER BY CODIGO
```

but i have codigo= 6000,6100,6101,6101,6101,6101,6102,6102,6103,6104 and i don't need repeated.

Any suggestion please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spec says

> I need select by lenght of Codigo

but your query is filter by `WHERE LEN(CODIGO)>=4`

Try using `DISTINCT` instead and match the ORDER BY clause, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MID(CODIGO, 1, 4) AS CODIGOB, TITULO
FROM MAYOR
WHERE LEN(CODIGO) = 4
ORDER BY MID(CODIGO, 1, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks Lars, i think the problem is TITULO. If use                    "SELECT DISTINCT MID(CODIGO, 1, 4) AS CODIGOB
FROM MAYOR
WHERE LEN(CODIGO) = 4
ORDER BY MID(CODIGO, 1, 4)" then run ok.